# How to pass or/and read two or more different ID

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, get

I want to get the particular insurance for the particular client. When I got to the url {clientId}/insurances/{insuranceId} with this code below. I end up getting 404 error. How may I able to solve it? Am I using correct method?

```
[HttpGet("{clientId}/insurances/{insuranceId}")]
public IActionResult Get(int clientId, int insuranceId)
{
    var insurances = context.PatientIntakeInsurances.SingleOrDefault(i => i.insurance_id == insuranceId);
    if (insurances == null)
        return HttpNotFound();
    return new ObjectResult(insurances);
}
```

**Here is my javascript code

```
state("clients.detail.insurances.detail", {
url: "/{insuranceId:[0-9]{1,10}}",
templateUrl: "clients/clients.detail.insurances.detail.html",
controller: ("$scope", "$log", "clientsService", "$stateParams",
function ($scope, $log, clientsService, $stateParams)
{
     clientsService.getInsurance($stateParams.clientId,$stateParams.insuranceId,
     function (insurances) 
     {
           $scope.insurances = insurances;
     })
}
```

**Here is my service

```
getInsurance: function(clientId, insuranceId, callback){
    $http({
        method: "GET", 
        url: "/api/clients/" +clientId +"/insurances/" + insuranceId 
       // url: "/api/insurances/" + id
    }).then(function(response){
        if(typeof callback === "function")
            callback(response.date);
    }, function(response){
    });
},
```

Comment: Show your javascript that calls the controller action. Is your action being hit when you put a breakpoint?

Comment: I edited my post sir, regarding to the breakpoint, yes, it will be hit.

Comment: Are you sure your database has data? does the clientId and insuranceId has the correct values when the action is being hit? maybe you could also show your clientsService

Comment: You're using a library to do the calls and you didn't specified which so it's very difficult to see if the URL is wrong, use the network inspector from chrome or firefox and double check the final url for the call.

Comment: @BonMacalindong will it return a GET 404 error if my database happened to be no data, sir? I did try adding some data still the same error I got. I also added my service to my question sir.

Comment: @Gusman the url in the service is the final url, sir.

Comment: Ok, I can see something here, you commented in the js code this line: *// url: "/api/insurances/" + id* and you stated before changing the call to support two id's it worked, so I belive your url is wrong, try with *url: "/api/insurances/" +clientId +"/insurances/" + insuranceId*

Comment: @Gusman no sir, that commented url is the last part of the url that I am using, and. Since I wanted to get the particular insurance of the particular client I added clientid. Which I guess the url the i am using is correct.

Comment: It will return 404 if it did not found your data. In your database, are there multiple rows that has the same insuranceId? if yes then you should use FirstOrDefault to just get one record. And i don't get it why you pass the clientId and not even using it.

Comment: Maybe you could show @Gusman your Route prefix so he can understand what you're saying regarding the url

Comment: no, look, you added "clients" on the url, and there's no place with that url... if I get it right you had before [HttpGet("insurances/{insuranceId}")] and now you have [HttpGet("{clientId}/insurances/{insuranceId}")], so the correct url must be url: "/api/" +clientId +"/insurances/" + insuranceId

Comment: @Gusman because you can specify a route prefix in your controller level sample is [RoutePrefix("api/clients")]. So he doesn't need to specify the base api path for each and every action in the controller.

Comment: @BonMacalindong Yes, I know that, but I assume the user didn't changed the prefix as he isn't posting it (but well, that can be my mistake, that's the problem with incomplete examples :/ )

Comment: Yup, that's why i told him to post his route prefix earlier.

Comment: I'll give you the flow gentlemen, on the first page we can see a client list. When I choose a client, which gives us the url `clients/clientId`, back to my question. I just want to pass the clientId inorder for me to get the data, the clientId supposedly already has its value. Did I explain it sir? Sorry I am so noob in this stackoverflow.

Comment: Ohhw, my rout prefix is `[Route("api/clients")]`, sorry sir.

Comment: It seems you're not sending insuranceId (or sending not existing one)